# PySpark truncate a decimal

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working in pySpark and I have a variable LATITUDE that has a lot of decimal places. I need to create two new variables from this, one that is rounded and one that is truncated. Both to three decimal places.

What is the simplest way to truncate a value?

For rounding, I did:

```
raw_data = raw_data.withColumn("LATITUDE_ROUND", round(raw_data.LATITUDE, 3))
```

This seems to work, but let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: And what's the problem with the line you suggest? It's far more readable than LostInOverflow's answer, if you ask me.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki I agree that round is more readable but Amber asked for truncate.

Comment: The line I have is good for rounding, but I wanted something similar for truncating. Thanks @LostInOverflow I think this will work!

Comment: OK. After the edit it makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import pow, lit
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
>>>
>>> num_places = 3
>>> m = pow(lit(10), num_places).cast(LongType())
>>> df = sc.parallelize([(0.6643, ), (0.6446, )]).toDF(["x"])
>>> df.withColumn("trunc", (col("x") * m).cast(LongType()) / m).
```

Comment: What if I just want values beofre decimal places without rounding the number? like values 123.9,123.2 both should yield 123.

Comment: @user1584253:  That sounds like the Floor function?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [the `floor()` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.floor). So (without testing) I'd suggest:

```
raw_data = raw_data.withColumn("LATITUDE_TRUNCATED", floor(raw_data.LATITUDE))
```

But watch out for negative values - as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344815/how-do-the-floor-and-ceiling-functions-work-on-negative-numbers

Comment: Floor returns an integer value - so this would truncate it without the 3 decimal places that the asker wants?

Answer (score 3):

**Spark 1.5.2**

You can simply use the [`format_number(col,d)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.format_number) function, which rounds the numerical input to `d` decimal places and returns it as a `string`. In your case:

```
raw_data = raw_data.withColumn("LATITUDE_ROUND", format_number(raw_data.LATITUDE, 3))
```

Comment: The asker is looking for a truncation, not a rounding, and I assume they want the result as a decimal I assume, not a string

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a simple UDF:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import math
@F.udf
def trunc_float(num,precision):
    return (math.trunc(flt*10**precision) / 10**precision) if num else num
```

Usage example:

```
df.select(trunc_float(F.lit(0.0017),F.lit(3)))
```

yields 0.001

UPDATED with comments below from @david-ahern

Comment: hi, you need to do this... divide by 10^precision after to get what you need... but otherwise good... i'm using it... thanks

`return math.trunc(num*10**precision) / 10**precision`

Comment: and to handle an edge case for nulls
`return (math.trunc(flt*10**precision) / 10**precision) if type(flt) is float else flt`

Comment: @DavidAhern upvotes are always welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Using a UDF with python's Decimal type. This is also useful is you have a UDF that already returns Decimal but need to avoid overflow since Python's Decimal can be larger than PySpark (max 38,18):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import decimal as D

@F.udf(T.DecimalType(38,18))
def trunc_precision(val:D.Decimal,precision:int):
    return val.quantize(D.Decimal(10)**-1*precision)
```